# Should I answer my own question if someone answered in the comments several months ago and still haven't responded to the request to post an answer?

Tags: discussion, story-identification, answers

A few months ago, I had written an identification question, to which someone gave a very possible answer in the comments, so I asked them if they could write an actual answer.

To this day, they haven't written an answer, despite being a very active user on the Stack Exchange community as a whole (I actually checked their activity to make sure they weren't inactive).

What is the correct course of action in this case? The question is technically answered but still appears as unanswered. A part of me wants to self-answer and be done with it, but at the same time it's not my answer either.

Comment: I'm tempted to make a community answer, but I was also told that's not what community answers are intended for.

Comment: That's not what community answers are intended for. They're not a "rep avoidance" tool

Comment: This question looks like it might be a duplicate of https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8131/cw-answers-for-story-id-questions-where-the-op-has-found-the-answer

Comment: Related, but not a dupe in my opinion

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A self answer is fine.

The point of the site is for correctly answered questions that might prove useful to others in the future.

**An acknowledgement of the commenter's assistance would be nice but is not mandatory.**

Answer (score 10):

Post your own answer and mark it as Accepted.

Optionally flag comment as "no longer needed" and a moderator may delete it.

---

Every time the annual Moderator survey comes around, there's a box asking "what would make your job easier?"

I request "convert comment to answer" as a natural inverse to the existing "convert answer to comment" function.

Once a comment is made into an answer it can be edited and improved by the community at large.  Comments cannot be edited by the community.

And if the comment is deleted without being transcribed as an answer, then that information is lost and the post becomes worse.

If the comment were transmogrified to an answer, then the poster will earn reputation.  Comment upvotes do not translate to Rep.

Answer (score 9):

I'd probably do one of two things;

- Prodding them with a comment saying something like *"Are you planning to turn that into an answer?"*

or

- Self-answering the question and acknowledging them, either in the answer itself if they've given me everything I need, or in the comments below if I had to do any level of research to turn it into an answer.

> This is *'The Shining'* (1980) starring Jack Nicholson.
>
> [*Blah blah blah*]
>
> Thanks to @User for identifying this in [a comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14023/20774)